# Recommended LESS Linter for Magento2

Tags: magento2, less

Is there a recommended tool for linting LESS code in Magento2? Interestingly, [ESLint Rules](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Js/_files/eslint/.eslintrc-magento) are provided for Javascript linting, but when it comes to LESS, all they seem to provide is a [coding standard](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/coding-standards/code-standard-less.html)...

I've tried using [grunt-eslint](https://github.com/jgable/grunt-lesslint), but it seems outdated (last commit was in 2017, and skeptical of its accuracy). There are some errors for example in my tiny starter theme complaining about missing variables, but when I run the LESS compiler it compiles just fine... Not to mention some smaller issues.

So what do folks use when it comes to linting LESS code for M2 projects?